# Call method with String return in another class

Tags: apex, method, constructor

I'm trying to get required information (**currentCompany()**) via method:

```
public without sharing class RemoveUserInfo implements Queueable {
    private List<User> users;
    private List<Account> accounts;
    
    public RemoveUserInfo(List<User> users, List<Account> accounts) {
        this.users = users;
        this.accounts = accounts;
    }
public String userName() {
        String userName = users.get(0).Id;
        return userName;
    }
    
    public String currentCompany() {
        String currentCompany = [SELECT Default_Company__c FROM User WHERE Id =: userName()].Default_Company__c.toLowercase();
        return currentCompany;
    }
}
```

And here is second class where I want to retrieve that String (as it is in **RemoveUserInfo** class)

```
public static void sentDataToUser(String sendingTo, User u) {
        try {
            RemoveUserInfo getData = new RemoveUserInfo();
            String currentUserBrand = getData.currentCompany();
                            **some code**
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex) {
            **some code**
        }
    }
```

But error in second class says something is wrong with constructor. I see my lack of knowledge in basics and reading it now, but any ideas how to overcome it? I want to call that String which defined in first class

Comment: The class RemoveUserInfo has a constructor with two parameters, yet with 'new RemoveUserInfo()' you give zero parameters. Either create a constructor without parameters, or call it with the required parameters.

Comment: @SanderdeJong If I create second empty constructor, the second class reads first constructor with parameters

Comment: you have to pass parameters, else currentCompany would not return any data, all those methods returns some value based on other methods.